# Complex combination of words in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need a function to combinate words from an array. Yet, I have tried it with recursion but do not have get it yet. This is the example array I have:

```
[1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "ar" [1]=> string(2) "to" [2]=> string(4) "tron" [3]=> string(3) "var" } 
[2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "to" } 
[3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "tron" } 
[4]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "ar" [1]=> string(2) "to" [2]=> string(4) "tron" [3]=> string(3) "var" }
```

This means, that at position 1 one of the Strings "ar", "to", "tron" and "var" can take place. On position two only the String "to" can take place. And so on.

The length of the words should be the length of the array (in this case 4). All possible words should be returned as an array. For example here:

```
["artotronar", "artotronto", "artotrontron", "artotronvar", "tototronar", ...]
```

My idea was to write a recursive function, but I did not succeed in it. :-(

Best Regards

Richard

Comment: Are you wanting this to return 'artotronvar', 'to', 'tron', 'artotronvar' ?

Comment: Yes, this should be returned as an array. Or better, it should be inserted into the database directly in the function, because this saves resources.

Comment: Excellent, I'll write you an answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$syllables = array(
    array('ar', 'to', 'tron', 'var'),
    array('to'),
    array('tron'),
    array('ar', 'to', 'tron', 'var'),
);
$words = array();
$k = 0;
$max = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i < count($syllables); $i++) {
    $max = max($max, count($syllables[$i]));
}
foreach ($syllables[0] as $syllable) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $words[$k] = $syllable;
        for ($j = 1; $j < count($syllables); $j++) {
            $words[$k] .= $syllables[$j][min($i, count($syllables[$j]) - 1)];
        }
        $k++;
    }
}

var_dump($words);
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a solution that will work for all inputs and generate every possible combination. The code assumes that $syllables will have at least one array.

```
<?php

$syllables = array(
    array('ar', 'to', 'tron', 'var'),
    array('to'),
    array('tron'),
    array('ar', 'to', 'tron', 'var'),
);

$p = 1;
foreach ($syllables as $syllableSet) {
    $p = $p * count($syllableSet);
}
$words = array();
$n0 = count($syllables[0]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $p; $i++) {
    $words[$i] = $syllables[0][$i % $n0];
}

for ($i = 1; $i < $n0; $i++) {
    $pos = 0;
    $ni = count($syllables[$i]);
    for ($k = 0; $k < $p / $n0; $k++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $n0; $j++) {
            $words[$pos] .= $syllables[$i][$k % $ni];
            $pos++;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($words);
```

Comment: Oh man thank you, I hit a dead end here and wasn't sure if somebody else was going to answer. I woulda got there eventually but was banging my head against a wall!

Comment: One comment: $max should be 1 at the begin, so that arrays with only one element are also support. This solution works very well, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I have updated my answer and the second solution is pretty much what you want. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the solution to your problem:

```
$pattern[] = array("ar", "to", "tron", "var");
$pattern[] = array("to");
$pattern[] = array("tron");
$pattern[] = array("ar", "to", "tron", "var");

$words = array();

foreach($pattern[0] as $p0) {
    foreach($pattern[1] as $p1) {
        foreach($pattern[2] as $p2) {
            foreach($pattern[3] as $p3) {
                $words[] = $p0.$p1.$p2.$p3;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($words);
echo "</pre>";
```

this will output all possible combinations of artotronvar, artotronar, etc...

but I didn't make a recursive function to call these...

and here are the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => artotronar
    [1] => artotronto
    [2] => artotrontron
    [3] => artotronvar
    [4] => tototronar
    [5] => tototronto
    [6] => tototrontron
    [7] => tototronvar
    [8] => trontotronar
    [9] => trontotronto
    [10] => trontotrontron
    [11] => trontotronvar
    [12] => vartotronar
    [13] => vartotronto
    [14] => vartotrontron
    [15] => vartotronvar
)
```

Comment: Yes, this works so far. But the number of Array elements is not known. This should be recursive.

Comment: Maybe something like that: `foreach($array[0] as $v){
   $newWord = $word . $v;
   if(isset($array[1])){
    array_shift($array);
    $words = array_merge($words, makewords($array, $newWord));
   } else {
    $words[] = $newWord;
   }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's my code, I re-wrote the array at the top which obviously you won't have to do, but I left it in there so that you can see how it looks.

```html
<?php

//The array that we are starting with
$parts = array(
    array(
        'ar',
        'to',
        'tron',
        'var',
    ),
    array(
        'to',
    ),
    array(
        'tron',
    ),
    array(
        'ar',
        'to',
        'tron',
        'var',
    ),
);

//Function to do our work
function makewords($parts){
    //Set up an empty array to use as well as a word string for us to manipulate
    $words = array();
    $word = null;
    
    //For each entry in this array
    foreach($parts as $x){
        
        //If this entry is also an array (it should be but this is just to make sure)
        if(is_array($x)){
            
            //Then for each of these entries...
            foreach($x as $y){
                //Create the word
                $word .= $y;
            }
            
            //At this point our word is finished, so add it to the words array
            $words[] = $word;
        }
        
        //Clear $word for the next one
        $word = null;
    }
    
    //Now our array is done, so let's return it
    return $words;
}

//Print it to check that it works
print_r(makewords($parts));
```

I hope this works for you.

To add it to the database, just add your database insert code where "return $words" is, however I'd do it this way and then enter it in to the database OUTSIDE of the function, otherwise the function will make an insert every time it's used; this way you can just use the function to create your array and then do what you please with it.

Comment: Thank you for your work, but this return this array: `array(4) { [0]=> string(11) "artotronvar" [1]=> string(2) "to" [2]=> string(4) "tron" [3]=> string(11) "artotronvar" }`

Comment: Sorry that's what I thought you wanted, I'm a little lost now. What exactly should it return?

Comment: I want to have the elements of the first array on the first word position and so on. So, all combinations should be built. It should not be possible to omit a position.

Comment: Oh you want every possible solution from each element? So from the first one you want every solution out of the 4 provided words, but then the 2nd one will only give "to" as it's the only element, correct? I think I understand now, gimme a while to figure this out.

Comment: Yes, this I want. I needed 3 hours yet and did not find a solution. Sure, there is one, but it is very complex to figure out.